# Use variables to add columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add columns according to my variables.
Like this:

```
for key in areadict:
    for key2 in methoddict:
        df[key + key2] = ''
```

I want to use the combination of key and key2 as the name of the new columns.

And after adding columns, can I access the value by df[key+key2]?

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data - areadict and methoddict and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made up two dicts to show you the behaviour:

```
areadict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
methoddict = {'_one': 11, '_two': 22, '_three': 33}

df = pd.DataFrame([0, 0, 0])

for key in areadict:
    for key2 in methoddict:
        df[key + key2] = areadict[key]
```

gives us:

```
   0  one_one  one_two  one_three  two_one  two_two  two_three  three_one  three_two  three_three
0  0        1        1          1        2        2          2          3          3            3
1  0        1        1          1        2        2          2          3          3            3
2  0        1        1          1        2        2          2          3          3            3
```

Setting the `df[key + key2]=''` works as well. We can access it with `df['one_two']` which results in

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
Name: one_two, dtype: int64
```